# How to define boundary numbers without decimal points - Geopandas

Tags: python, legend, geopandas, matplotlib, choropleth

**Problem**
The numbers in a legend has the decimal points (eg. 0.00-4.80 at the top of the legend box), when I want them to be integers without decimal points. All I care is that the boundary values are integers. It doesn't matter whether a certain region in a choropleth is labelled as the category A or B, as long as the A, B and other categories are separated by the integer values so that legend box shows only integer separations.

It's because I am making these maps for publishing articles after the Korean election is over. It would be much easier for the newspaper readers to have the integer numbers in legend!

**My current graph**
[image: eng]

**My code**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xkcd()
seoul=gpd.read_file('../json/seoul_municipalities_geo.json')
# You can download the same file from the Github below
# https://github.com/southkorea/seoul-maps/tree/master/juso/2015/json

data_result.plot(figsize=(14,10),linewidth=0.25, edgecolor='black', column='ESRI_PK',cmap='Blues',scheme='quantiles',legend=True)

for index,row in seoul.iterrows():
    xy=row['geometry'].centroid.coords[:]
    xytext=row['geometry'].centroid.coords[:]
    plt.annotate(row['SIG_ENG_NM'],xy=xy[0], xytext=xytext[0],  horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')
    plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'boundary'?

Comment: @Kadir Sorry for not clarifying the meaning of 'boundary'! Boundary here means each of 5 classifications that are in legends. To be precise, what I meant by boundaries are '0.00 - 4.80' , '4.80 - 9.60', '9.60 - 14.40', '14.40 - 19.20' and '19.20 - 24.00'. 

And my question is whether I can make those classification done with integers, not with float (0.00, 4.80, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to add integer values to the label is by making the legend yourself with `plt.legend()` and adding Patches to this legend with the correct labels and colours.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

plt.xkcd()
seoul = gpd.read_file('./data/seoul_municipalities_geo.json')
# You can download the same file from the Github below
# https://github.com/southkorea/seoul-maps/tree/master/juso/2015/json

seoul.plot(figsize=(14,10),linewidth=0.25, edgecolor='black', column='ESRI_PK', cmap='Blues', scheme='quantiles')

for index, row in seoul.iterrows():
    xy = row['geometry'].centroid.coords[:]
    xytext = row['geometry'].centroid.coords[:]
    plt.annotate(row['SIG_ENG_NM'], xy=xy[0], xytext=xytext[0], horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
    plt.axis('off')

cmap = cm.get_cmap('Blues')
white_patch = mpatches.Patch(color=cmap(0.0), label='0 - 5')
lowblue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color=cmap(0.25), label='5 - 10')
midblue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color=cmap(0.5), label='10 - 14')
highblue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color=cmap(0.75), label='14 - 19')
veryblue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color=cmap(1.0), label='19 - 24')
plt.legend(handles=[white_patch, lowblue_patch, midblue_patch, highblue_patch, veryblue_patch])

plt.show()
```

[image: Result_image]